# Formatting SQL query output in Python/SQLite 3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I use a simple SQL query in Python to grab records from a SQLite 3 database:

```
cursor.execute ("SELECT due, task FROM tasks WHERE due <> '' ORDER BY due ASC")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
            for row in rows:
                print '\n%s %s' % (row[0], row[1])
```

The *due* field in the database is set to DATE type, so the query returns the data in this field formatted as *2010-07-20 00:00:00.00* How can I remove the *00:00:00.00*, so the result contains only the date? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think row[0] is a [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) object. So the following should work:

```
print '\n%s %s' % (row[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), row[1])
```

Comment: you could also write the query like `SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', due), ...`